# Relative path clarification

Tags: java

Project file system:

```
Project
|
-----bin
|
 -----.settings
|
-----src
     |
     -----(default package)
          |
          -----Main.Java
          |
          -----neuropol x rg.ttf
```

I have a program which sets a font like so:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("/neuropol x rg.ttf")));
```

Which work perfectly. The thing I'm trying to figure out is how the relative path is working though. So the `neuropol x rg.ttf` file is sitting in my `src` folder, so in order to work you would think that the path should be:

```
...getResourcesAsStream("/src/neuropol x rg.ttf")
```

But it works fine the way I have it at the top of the post. To my understanding the relative paths root should be wherever the code is run from, which in this case is my Project Folder, which I have confirmed by inserting the following line right below where the font is created:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

This line returns the project folder. So how come it is working without adding the src folder to the path? Am I confused as to where the root of the relative path is?

Comment: When your code is compiled the `src/` folder doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) opens a *resource*, not a *file*.  The resource could be a file in a directory, but it could be an entry in a jar file or any other place that the JVM can find resources.  The javadoc discusses how the JVM performs the search for the specified resource.

The key point is that the resource name is relative to the CLASSPATH, not to the Current Working Directory.  That is why you can not prefix the path with '/src', though if you were to open a file (eg 'new FileInputStream(...)`) you would -- but only when the program is run from the project source directory (not when installed on a user's computer, though).

Comment: Both awesome answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`src` is just the package structure for the project and isn't included when you compile. `(Default package)` is what happens when you have no package name causing you to use `/yourFont.ttf`. As an example if you have a package name:

```
-----src
     |
     -----yourpackage
          |    
          -----neuropol x rg.ttf
// This will become getResourceAsStream("/yourpackage/neuropol x rg.ttf")

-----src
     |
     -----yourpackage
          | 
          -----Main.java
          |    
          -----fonts
               |
               -----neuropol x rg.ttf
// This will become getResourceAsStream("/yourpackage/fonts/neuropol x rg.ttf")
```